# Reassign task to different user in SharePoint 2013 workflow using SPD

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-online, task-list

I have a requirement in which there is an approval for cost.

In this request will be assigned to manager and if manager approves the task and if cost is more then 20000 then it should assign to COO for approval.
else item should get approved by manager it self.

How can I re-assign the task to COO which is already approved by manager ?

How can I change the task status from Approved to Pending ?

I am using SharePoint 2013 platform for work-flow in Office 365.

Answer (score 1):

You would simply create another approval task and assign it to the COO. This is a separate approval needed on top of the manager approval, so you wouldn't want to edit the manager's approval task.

Comment: No Eric, I cant assign that task directly to COO. If manager approves it and amount in bill is higher then manager approve limit, then only I need to assign that task to COO. Otherwise for lower limits manager can directly approve or reject it. And for even this bill also manager is having permission to reject. Eg bill is 14 and manager's approv limit is 10, then manager can reject bill of 14 and if he approves bill then only it should assigned to the COO. Otherwise not. Thanks for your efforts.